# program in C++ in OOP structure, splitting it at least into 3 files

Tags: c++, oop, methods

I am doing my c ++ homework and am having difficulty in one little thing
Here is the text:

> Create program in C++ in OOP structure, splitting it at least into 3 files. The class header should be put in header file (program.h). All the methods should be implemented outside the header – in a special C++ file (program.cpp). Function main should be put in yet another C++ file (main.cpp). By default, all class fields are private, but class methods - public. Unlike previous programs, it is not required to follow specific interface rules.
>
> Create class "Date" with three numbers stored - year, month, day. The following class methods should be created: (1) a constructor to initialize an object with given initial values, (2) destructor which should notify about deleting the object, (3) method "change" with 3 parameters, (4) method "day" – which calculates and prints the weekday of date, (5) method "print", which prints the date.

I created 3 files main.cpp program.h programm.cpp

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "program.h"


using namespace std;


int main() {
    Date s= Date(2002, 02, 18);
    s.print();
    s.change(1996, 02, 18);
    s.print();
    s.day();
    return 0;
}
```

program.h

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Date {
    public:
        Date() {
            year = 0;
            month = 0;
            dayc = 0;
        }
        //counstructor
        Date(int n_year, int n_month, int n_day) {
            year = n_year;
            month = n_month;
            dayc = n_day;
        }
        //destructor
        ~Date() {
            std::cout << "Destructor deleted Date " << year << " " << month << " " << dayc << " " << std::endl;
        }

        void change(int c_year, int c_month, int c_day) {
            year = c_year;
            month = c_month;
            dayc = c_day;
        }

        void day() {
            //LONG CODE WITH CALCULATION
        }

        void print() {
            std::cout << "Date is " << dayc << " " << month << " " << year << " " << std::endl;
        }
    private:
        int year;
        int month;
        int dayc;
};

#endif
```

and empty programm.cpp

I need to do the OOP part and separate code to 3 files

Comment: This isn't really OOP related. And I guess the assignment is to put the implementation of the `Date` member functions inside the `program.cpp` source file.

Comment: Since this is a class, presumably you have a textbook or other reference sources that show examples of classes being split up into multiple files. As an example, take `Date::day()` which has a long code with a calculation. In `program.h`, you would just put `void day();` to declare the member function. Then, in `program.cpp`, you would put `void Date::day() { // implementation here }`.

Answer (score 1):

The homework assignment tells you to separate code from the header. To do this you need to leave only declarations in the header like so:

Program.h:

```
#include <iostream>

class Date {
public:
  Date(int, int, int);
  void day();
private:
 int _year;
 int _month;
 int _day;
};
```

Program.cpp:

```
#include "Program.h"

Date::Date(int year, int month, int day):
  _year(year),
  _month(month),
  _day(day)
{
  // only code should go here, not initializations
  std::cout << "Constructor called" << std::endl;
}

void Date::day()
{
  // your calculation
}
```

Your question suggests you haven't used more translation units yet, so you have to compile the Program.cpp first without linking (check your compiler manual), probably something like

c++ -o program.o -c program.cpp

and then compile + link the executable

c++ main.cpp program.o && ./a.out

Comment: Thank you, im already solved my question with editing program.h and transferring all methods to program.cpp with added Date:: to all methods